# Open a structure of substructures of matlab with python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, structure

I have a structure of substructures as an output of a matlab file. Every substructure has four variables from which three are arrays. I would like to access every single value of this data with python.

Does anybody have any idea on how I can do that? I am new in python. I have already installed numpy and scipy.

```
% ----MATLAB FILE EXAMPLE----
main_struct{ 
         substruct1{atr1,atr2[1X64],atr3[50X64],atr4[50X64]}  
         substruct2{atr1,atr2[1X64],atr3[50X64],atr4[50X64]}
          .
          .
          .
         substructn{atr1,atr2[1X64],atr3[50X64],atr4[50X64]}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show an example of your expected output?

Comment: i would like for example to have acces in main_struct{substructn{atr3[3,4]}} in order to do some maths with that value.The output cant be explained cause the whole process is really complicated as i want to calculate the perplexity of a continuous language model and the stractures i want to import in python are my model

Comment: Ok I posted a new answer.

Comment: please consider marking the answer as accepted if this helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You can read matlab(.mat) files in Python, try this:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
mat = loadmat('file.mat')
```

Then you access your structure with:

```
my_struct = mat['variable_name_in_matlab']
```

After that you can do

```
>>> print my_struct.shape
(1, 1)
>>> val = my_struct[0,0]
>>> print val
([[1.0]], [[2.0]])
>>> print val['field1']
[[ 1.]]
>>> print val['field2']
[[ 2.]]
>>> print val.dtype
[('field1', '|O8'), ('field2', '|O8')]
```

You can see more details [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html#matlab-structs)

Comment: yes i know. The stuctures i discribed are in a mat file which i have already loaded with the way you suggested.But after that i cant acces the atributes of the substructures.
However many thnx for your help

Comment: @user1866935, well try to `print mat` and show some part of it so we can help you access it.

Comment: -4.24863135, -3.33222203, -4.04780321, -6.0400155 , -4.65374329,
        -4.43081276, -6.04002306, -4.24841015, -3.96079369, -2.90905874,
        -4.24849134, -5.34706737, -4.24848014, -4.24845494, -4.02538433,
        -4.16416999, -3.56939831, -4.43083292, -6.73315596, -4.65440024,
        -4.53613492, -3.84305027, -5.34705876, -4.65398645, -4.78722758,
        -4.04780321, -4.24863415, -6.73316772, -4.78748086, -3.56939831,
        -5.34706737, -2.81543209, -6.04017171, -4.16416999]]))]])]], 
      
dtype=[('mixture1000', 'O'), ('mixture1001', 'O'), ('mixture1002', 'O'),

Comment: @user1866935, ok I updated my answer. From your output it seems that your field names are 'mixture1001', etc...

Answer (score 0):

Should be converted to `dict` in python.

```
main_struct['substruct1']['atr2']
```

should be the python equivalent of

```
main_struct.substruct1.atr2
```

in matlab.

Comment: i tried this but when it comes to get the atributes value i get
ValueError: field named nmix not found.
(nmix is my attributes name)

Moreover the atributes which are arrays are displayed as single variables and not as arrays